# Track accrued dyno usage on Heroku

Tags: heroku, usage-statistics

I'm unable to track how many dyno hours and add-ons I have used in a month. The gauge in the scaling dashboard shows only a monthly estimate.

Is there any source where I can check my monthly usage balance?

Comment: I'm interested in this too :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Login to heroku.com and go to My Account. Scroll down to the billing section and there should be a' Current Usage' block with a 'Details' button - that will show you an invoice to date.

Direct Link: https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/billing

Comment: Great, thanks! This is not described anywhere else, at least I couldn't find it. Even if the question gets closed the documentation will stay here. :)

Comment: Here's a direct link https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/billing. Click on View Details next to "Current Usage"